# React hooks - update state from an input in a child component which is called on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I’m trying to update a state from an input, which works fine when the field is is in the same component, but doesn’t work when I pass it into a child component, seemingly no matter what I pass to it!

```
const Create = () => {
      const [question, setQuestion] = useState(''); 
      const [components, setComponents] = useState([""]); 

        const handleQInputChange = event => {
              setQuestion(event.target.value)
        }
        
        function addComponent() {
        setComponents([...components, "Question"]) 
}

return (

       <Button onClick={addComponent} text="Next question"/>
            <ol>
                    {components.map((item, i) => ( 
                        <li>
                            <CreateQuestion question={question} onChange= 
                            {handleQInputChange}/>
                        </li> 
                    ))} 
                
            </ol>
)}
```

and then CreateQuestion component looks like:

```
     const CreateQuestion = (props) => {

    function handleQInputChange( event ) {
    props.onChange(event.target.value)
    }


    return (
      
        
         <div className="Component">
                <label>Question</label>
                <input
                    name="question"
                    id="question"
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange={props.handleQInputChange}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Question"
                />
                <br />
```

I've followed at least 10 guides on how to pass the data back and forth, so it may have become a little convoluted.  If I put the Question input directly into the parent component the state updates, so I suspect it's just me not passing props correctly but completely stuck!

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but on a glance at your code, it's apparently that you're reference several props in `CreateQuestion` that you are not passing in from `Create`. Namely `handleQInputChange` (I assume this is supposed to be `onchange` as that is what you call the prop) and `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of wrong things:

- Using wrong props.
- Passing `event.target.value` which is a string, to `props.onChange` which is a
  function that accepts a type `Event`.
- Declaring the controlled input state on the parent, while you need the state local to the input, since you have multiple inputs and I don't think you want to share the same state among them.

```js
function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const [components, setComponents] = useState(['']);

  function addComponent() {
    setComponents([...components, 'Question']);
  }
  function addQuestion(question) {
    setQuestions((qs) => [...qs, question]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={addComponent} text="Next question" />
      <ol>
        {components.map((item, i) => (
          <li>
            <CreateQuestion idx={i} addQuestion={addQuestion} />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
      <ul>
        <h5>Submitted Questions:</h5>
        {questions.map((question, i) => (
          <li>
            <span style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>
              Question n.{question.id}
            </span>
            <span>{question.body}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

const CreateQuestion = ({ addQuestion, idx }) => {
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setQuestion(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addQuestion({ id: idx + 1, body: question });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="Component">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label></label>
        <input
          name="question"
          id="question"
          value={question}
          onChange={handleChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Question"
        />
        <button>ADD QUESTION</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I refactored your code in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h7m1cu check if it helps you.
I fixed the main issues, moved the input state down to the `CreateQuestion` Component, added a function and a state to the *Parent Component* that holds all the *questions* added when you submit the input, this way you can handle *data* in your *Parent*, if for example you want to send it to your server.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your CreateQuestion component like below

```
const CreateQuestion = (props) => {
    return (
         <div className="Component">
             <label>Question</label>
             <input
               name="question"
               id="question"
               value={props.value}
               onChange={props.onChange}
               type="text"
               placeholder="Question"
             />
         </div>
    );
 }
```

**The problem** is

You use an attribute like

```
onChange={props.handleQInputChange}
```

But you do not have handleQInputChange when you call your component as an attribute

```
<CreateQuestion question={question} onChange= 
                            {handleQInputChange}/>
```